# Nowhere dense sets of product topology

Tags: functional-analysis, baire-category

If $X$ = {$0$} $\cup$ {$\frac{1}{n}$: $n\in$ $\Bbb N$}, a metric and topological space, and $Y$ = $X$ x $X$ with the usual $\Bbb R^2$ metric, what are the nowhere dense subsets of $Y$, and the subsets of first category in $Y$?

Comment: HINT: Start by finding the isolated points of $Y$, because a set that contains an isolated point of the space cannot be nowhere dense (why?).

Comment: A single point is closed in the metric space so it equals its closure. But the interior of a single point is the null space. And the null space is nowhere dense trivially.

Comment: The interior of a singleton is *not* necessarily empty. For instance, the interior of $\left\{\frac13\right\}$ in $X$ is $\left\{\frac13\right\}$.

Comment: But how is the interior of a single point in $Y$ just the point? With the given metric

Comment: It happens automatically if the point is an isolated point, meaning that its singleton is an open set. That’s why I suggested that you start by finding the isolated points of $Y$.

Comment: Are not all the points in $Y$ isolated? no wait, $0$ isn't?

Comment: Of course not. That would be true only if every point of $X$ were isolated, which is not the case.

Comment: What point in $X$ isn't isolated other than $0$?

Comment: $0$ is the only isolated point of $X$. Its existence guarantees that there are non-isolated points in $Y$; what are they?

Comment: All points in $Y$ except for $(0,0)$?

Comment: You’re right that $\langle 0,0\rangle$ is not isolated in $Y$, but there are infinitely many other non-isolated points as well. (A sketch of $Y$ really helps quite a bit.)

Comment: Ohh I see that now. And once I know the isolated/non-isolated points in a set, how can I use that to find the nowhere dense subsets? Sorry for the Questions, I've never used isolated points for this before

Comment: I found online that {1/n : n in N} is nowhere dense, but yet are not the 1/n's isolated points?

Comment: You have to pay attention to the space as well as the set. That set is nowhere dense in $\Bbb R$, but it’s dense in the space $X$.